# Improving spaCy memory usage and run time when running on 400K+ documents?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I currently have around 400K+ documents, each with an associated group and id number. They average around 24K characters and 350 lines each. In total, there is about 25 GB worth of data. Currently, they are split up by the group, reducing the number of documents need to process to around 15K at one time. I have run into the problem of both memory usage and segmentation faults (I believe the latter is a result of the former) when running on a machine with 128GB of memory. I have changed how I process the documents by using batching to handle them at one time.

**Batch Code**

```
def batchGetDoc(raw_documents):
        out = []
        reports = []
        infos = []
        # Each item in raw_documents is a tuple of 2 items, where the first item is all 
        # information (report number, tags) that correlate with said document. The second 
        # item is the raw text of the document itself 
        for info, report in raw_documents:
            reports.append(report)
            infos.append(info)

        # Using en_core_web_sm as the model
        docs = list(SPACY_PARSER.pipe(reports))
        for i in range(len(infos)):
            out.append([infos[i],docs[i]])
        return out
```

I use a batch size of 500, and even then, it still takes a while. Are these issues in both speed and memory due to using `.pipe()` on full documents rather than sentences? Would it be better to go through and run `SPACY_PARSER(report)` individually?

I am using spaCy to get the named entities, their linked entities, the dependency graphs, and knowledge bases from each document. Will doing it this way risk losing information that will be important for spaCy later on when it comes to getting said data?

Edit: I should mention that I do need the document info for later use in predicting the accuracy based on the document's text

Comment: You can try to lose the for loops for starters

Comment: @pissall Will do. How should I match up the document info to the docs returned from spaCy?

Answer (score 1):

There was a memory leak in the parser and NER, which is fixed in v2.1.9 and v2.2.2, so update if necessary. If you have very long documents, you might want to split them into paragraphs or sections for processing. (You'll get an error for texts longer than 1,000,000 characters.)

Definitely use `nlp.pipe()` for faster processing. You could use the `as_tuples` option with `nlp.pipe()` to pass in `(text, context)` tuples and get `(doc, context)` tuples back, so you won't need multiple loops. You'd have to handle reversing your tuples from the code above, but once you have `(text, context)` tuples, you'd just need something like:

```
out = nlp.pipe(raw_documents, as_tuples=True)
```